# Java Loop not giving Desired results

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to programming and learning java now.
I have written below code however I am not gettin correct result :-

```
public class LifeTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        for(x = 0; x < 3 ; x++); {
            int y = -1; //y is initialized each time block is entered
            System.out.println("y is : " + y); // this always prints -1
            y = 100;
            System.out.println("Y is : " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

THE result of this comes as :-

y is : -1
Y is : 100

there are nor repetitions till 3, why ?

same behavior is observed in all the loop programms that I have written

Can you please help ?

Comment: remove teh extra semicolon after ;x++); as loop is running their.

Comment: Do you mean you get only one line of output? And what do you mean why "same behaviour is observed in all the loop programs that I have written"?

Comment: @Abhay OP has got syntax wrong. Whenever he is writing loops,he putting ; after braces, creating empty body

Answer (score 14):

You have a spurious semicolon between the `for` loop and what you think is the body. Eliminate that and it should work as expected.

```
for(x = 0; x < 3 ; x++); {
                       ^
                       |
                eliminate this
```

What's happening now is that the `for` loop is looping three times and each time it is executing the empty statement formed by the semicolon. Then the block statement that you want executed three times is being executed once.

Comment: 1 up-vote for question and 14 up-votes for an answer O_O